# What is the best API to generate editable merged letters and export them to word?

Tags: java, apache, jasper-reports, apache-poi

I am currently working on a web application which should generate an editable merged letter which then have to be exported into different formats like '.docx' and '.pdf'. The application is going to be based on the Spring framework. Please suggest good tutorials for the APIs if you can. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to answer a question I asked a while ago the possible APIs are APACHE POI and BIRT
As for the tutorilas for Apache POI http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-3-apache-poi-hibernate-creating.html would be a great start